# Default NFC commands

Tags: nfc

I'm trying to figure out how one encodes an NFC tag so that it provokes default behavior on NFC enabled devices akin to what's depicted in this youtube video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQFrQLpxhno

My assumption is that the NFC tag must contain the instruction for the listening device to use whatever means it can to follow a link (?)... I'm guessing of course, but that would make sense.  My bigger question is where do I find the full spec for what default commands are possible via NFC.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find command specifications for various types of NFC tags at http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/#tagtypes

Message types, to which an NFC-enabled device may respond, are detailed at http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/#rtds

Comment: Hello NFC , we are developing an app which have to deal with mifare cards and POS machines , I have researched a lot and came across your answers at stackoverflow many times but unfortunately I don't have enough basics about the topic to understand those things clearly , I have been trying for long but no success so far  can you please help me.